# How to create a new login in ssms2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to make a new login in SSMS. I need it for the presistnase.xml in java jpa.

I click in security -> logins -> new login and I choose SQL Server Authentication.
I write user name and password.

Them i try to connect with the new login, and  I get the following message:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------
Cannot connect to DESKTOP-MJ1GR85.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Login failed for user 'n'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476
```

Comment: You can find answer with a simple search. check this link https://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2016/tutorial/create_a_login_in_sql_server_2016.cfm

Answer (score 0):

there are two steps: create a user, then give that user a role in the selected database. eg:

-- create a user:

```
CREATE LOGIN myUserName WITH PASSWORD=N'newPassword', DEFAULT_DATABASE = MASTER, 
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = US_ENGLISH;
```

-- give that user access to the database, by allocating a role in the db:

```
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [myUserName];
```

note: I wouldn't recommend a user name as short as n